# How to properly pass buffer pointers to Linux system calls in x86_64 assembly?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls

Hello I am trying to learn how to make system calls with x86_64 assembly on Linux. I am running into an issue where I can't seem to figure out how to properly pass the argument for [`getpeername`](https://www.gta.ufrj.br/ensino/eel878/sockets/getpeernameman.html).

In this link using C it looks like they are using the address of operator to pass the arguments. I can't figure out how to replicate this out in assembly. Here is the strace when I use no brackets for my buffer.

First I defined my buffer in the section .data

```
ip_buff:  times 14 db 0
.length: equ $-ip_buff
```

This is a macro

```
%define SYS_getpeername 52
```

`r12` stores the return value from the socket accept call

```
syscall getpeername,r12,ip_buff,15
```

Here is the strace not using brackets

```
[pid   749] accept(3, NULL, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid   761] read(4, "", 1024)           = 0
[pid   761] write(1, "", 0)             = 0
[pid   761] getpeername(4, 0x600733, 0xf) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

Here is the strace for when I do use brackets.

```
[pid   749] accept(3, NULL, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid   745] read(4, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:"..., 1024) = 78
[pid   745] write(1, "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 127.0.0.1:"..., 78) = 78
[pid   745] getpeername(4, NULL, 0xf)   = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

How can I properly make this system call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual problem is not with the buffer but with its length. Notice in the prototype you have `socklen_t *addrlen` so that should be a pointer. The value `15` that you pass is not a pointer hence the `-EFAULT`.

You should change the `.length: equ $-ip_buff` to `ip_length: dd $-ip_buff` and then use `syscall getpeername,r12,ip_buff,ip_length`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works perfectly appreciate it